# Error en homestead con driver SQL Server al guardar session de laravel (DB-Library (como ISQL) u ODBC versión 3.7)

Tags: sql-server, laravel-5, ubuntu, session, odbc

Estoy guardando mi Session en la base de datos utilizando laravel con SQL Server en homestead (Ubuntu) y al momento de entrar en el sistema me muestra este error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 4004 Unicode data in a Unicode-only
>   collation or ntext data cannot be sent to clients using DB-Library
>   (such as ISQL) or ODBC version 3.7 or earlier. [4004] (severity 16)
>   [select top 1 * from [sessions] where [id] =
>   'nbcccjhQEpucEpLoecby3FHrgkQ04TOXNJbieaZL'] (SQL: select top 1 * from
>   [sessions] where [id] = nbcccjhQEpucEpLoecby3FHrgkQ04TOXNJbieaZL)

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comento la solución por si le sirve a alguien en el futuro:

1. Entrar en homestead
2. Hacer vagrant ssh
3. Ir con el comando cd al directorio /etc/freetds
4. Abrir el archivo freetds.conf con el comando siguiente: `sudo nano freetds.conf`
5. Cambiar la linea:

> `#TDS protocol version`
>
> `tds version = 4.2`

por

> `tds version = 8.0`

6. Reiniciar el servidor con el comando: `service nginx restart`